# Media Player streaming, when Exit app music should stop

Tags: android, audio, media-player, exit

I currently have a mediaplayer streaming some mp3 files. What I would like to do is if the User presses the home button to exit the app, the music stops playing. how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your app' `onPause()` or `onDestroy()` call `mediaPlayer.stop()`.

Comment: i did: `@override public void onDestroy(){mediaPlayer.stop()}` and my application force closes

Comment: you forgot to call super.onDestroy()

Answer (score -1):

```
@Override 
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {     
if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)) {         
Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "home button pressed");     }     
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); }
```

Something like this, except instead of log, do whatever you do in your implementation to kill the service/asynctask/thread handling your music.

Answer (score -1):

Add this method to your class to override your home button

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME) {
            media.stop();
            finish();
            //or complete end your application
        //System.runFinalizersOnExit(true);
        //System.exit(0);

        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: i tried this and it force closed my app. when i removed it, it still force closed my app. how can i fix it now?

Comment: If either you have it or doesn't have it, your app still force close. then i suggest you made mistake in somewhere else in your code (and I didn't have your code to see it) :]