# MediaController BACK button not work

Tags: android

I have a music app with `MediaPayer` and `MediaController` and when music play and i hit back button can't let the activity exit.
I found from source code that `MediaController` capture the `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK` in `MediaController#dispatchKeyEvent()`. so I override the method by adding following code:

```
if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
    return false;
}
return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
```

But it still no luck.

Comment: You want to stop the music playback and exit from your application,when the back button is pressed right?

Comment: @Giridharan, yes. the mediaplayer is runing in service. So when I exit from activity, music could still play. I just was confused that why not work well after overriding the MediaController#dispatchKeyEvnt()

Comment: Then just add finish()  it will close everything.

Comment: Adding finish() can solve this  problem, but why overriding can't fix this?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457929/media-player-streaming-when-exit-app-music-should-stop

Comment: ok, this likely can solve my confusion, Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

I came across this problem too. The solution to my problem was none of them above, was setting MediaController after VideoView prepared. See the code:

```
videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(final MediaPlayer mp) {
            videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also override hide() method to show mediaController for every time like this:

```
mediaController = new MediaController(this){
     @Override
     public void hide() {
         //do Nothing
     }     

     //Handle BACK button
     @Override
     public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
         if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
             super.hide();//Hide mediaController
             finish();//Close this activity
             return true;//If press Back button, finish here
         }
         //If not Back button, other button (volume) work as usual.
         return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
     }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to release the MediaPlayer before you can execute finish() or onBackPressed(), this worked for me:

```
videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(final MediaPlayer mp) {
                MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(MyActivity.this){
                    @Override
                    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
                        if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
                            mp.release();
                            super.hide();//Hide mediaController
                            finish();//Close this activity
                            return true;//If press Back button, finish here
                        }
                        //If not Back button, other button (volume) work as usual.
                        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
                    }
                };
                videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
                videoView.start();
            }
        });
```