# Close video in VideoView when I press back button

Tags: android, video, gridview, android-videoview

I want to close a VideoView when I press the back button and the video is playing.

Here my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public Integer[] mVideo = {
            R.raw.clesella, R.raw.simonino,
            R.raw.ennio, R.raw.zip,
            R.raw.pippo, R.raw.monituri
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setAdapter(new VideoAdapter(this));

        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
               final VideoView mVideoView2 = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video);
                String uriPath = "android.resource://"+ getPackageName()+"/"+mVideo[position];
                Uri uri2 = Uri.parse(uriPath);
                mVideoView2.setVideoURI(uri2);
                mVideoView2.requestFocus();
                mVideoView2.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
                gridview.setVisibility(view.GONE);

                mVideoView2.start();

                mVideoView2.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        //write your code after complete video play
                        mVideoView2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        gridview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                });

                mVideoView2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                        if (mVideoView2.isPlaying()) {
                            mVideoView2.pause();
                        return  false;
                        }
                        else {
                            mVideoView2.start();
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        });
    }
}
```

As you can see, I take videos from the raw folder and I fill in a GridView. When I tap on the item, the video starts. I want to make the VideoView GONE and the GridView visible like I did in setOnCompletetionListener but when the video is playing and I press the back button.

Answer (score 2):

make your `mVideoView2` and `gridview` global to your class as shown and plus you don't create anonymous `new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener()`  on every click, just create a global listener and apply it .

```
class XY extends ..{
    GridView gridview;
    VideoView mVideoView2 


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
       gridview.setAdapter(new VideoAdapter(this));
       mVideoView2 = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video);
        mVideoView2.setOnCompletionListener(listner);

       gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
          // other code to play and listen
           }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(videoView.isPlaying()){ // check if video is playing then hide views
            mVideoView2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            gridview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          }else{  
               super.onBackPressed();
          }
      }

      MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener listner = 
                        new new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener(){
      //... add the code here 
     } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if (mVideoView2.isPlaying()) {
        mVideoView2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        gridview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Exactly where i have to put this part of code ? Sorry for the question,i'm starting now with android develop.

Comment: You should put it in your `MainActivity`.
Just start typing `onBack` and use `Ctrl+Space`....and the magic happens ;)

Comment: Anywhere in your activity.

Comment: dude you need to modify your answer because `super.onBackPressed();` will finish the activity

Answer (score 0):

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65719226/15254470) check this answer it worked for me and I bet it would work for you.

So the idea is to release mediaController on the *onPreparedListener* After that you can call this *dispatchKeyEvent* and check for *KEYCODE_BACK*. It will be done this way.